# Take the nearest row by condition in date, student frame

Tags: sql, sql-server, frame

I am struggling to get the nearest 'Math Test' or 'Biology Test' in (+/- 3 hours) from Test= 'Marked A+' including TestOrder ordering.

If 'Math Test' or 'Biology Test' were before 'Marked A+' with the same time - I get the max TestOrder to the 'Marked A+'

If 'Math Test' or 'Biology Test' were after 'Marked A+' with the same time - I get the min TestOrder to the 'Marked A+'

```
| student | Test         | TestOrder | DateTime                |
| ------- | ------------ | --------- | ----------------------- |
| 1       | Math Test    | 22        | 2022-05-01 19:06:16.207 |
| 1       | Biology Test | 32        | 2022-05-01 19:06:16.207 |
| 1       | Marked A+    | 50        | 2022-05-01 19:06:16.407 |
| 1       | Math Test    | 22        | 2022-05-01 20:06:16.100 |
| 1       | Biology Test | 32        | 2022-05-01 20:06:16.100 |
| 2       | Math Test    | 22        | 2022-05-01 18:06:16.407 |
| 2       | Biology Test | 32        | 2022-05-01 18:06:16.407 |
| 2       | Marked A+    | 50        | 2022-05-01 19:06:16.407 |
| 2       | Math Test    | 22        | 2022-05-01 19:07:16.407 |
| 2       | Biology Test | 32        | 2022-05-01 19:07:16.407 |
| 3       | Math Test    | 22        | 2022-05-01 10:36:12.207 |
| 3       | Biology Test | 32        | 2022-05-01 19:02:16.407 |
| 3       | Marked A+    | 50        | 2022-05-01 19:06:16.407 |
| 3       | Math Test    | 22        | 2022-05-01 20:06:14.002 |
| 3       | Biology Test | 32        | 2022-05-01 21:06:10.107 |
| 4       | Math Test    | 22        | 2022-05-01 17:06:22.101 |
| 4       | Biology Test | 32        | 2022-05-01 18:06:22.101 |
| 4       | Marked A+    | 50        | 2022-05-01 19:06:16.407 |
| 4       | Math Test    | 22        | 2022-05-01 19:06:20.407 |
| 4       | Biology Test | 32        | 2022-05-01 23:06:20.407 |
```

Final result has 'Marked A+' left joined to the nearest events 'Math Test' or 'Biology Test' across students.

```
| student | Test      | TestOrder | DateTime                | student\_ | Test\_       | TestOrder\_ | DateTime\_              |
| ------- | --------- | --------- | ----------------------- | --------- | ------------ | ----------- | ----------------------- |
| 1       | Marked A+ | 50        | 2022-05-01 19:06:16.407 | 1         | Biology Test | 32          | 2022-05-01 19:06:16.207 |
| 2       | Marked A+ | 50        | 2022-05-01 19:06:16.407 | 2         | Math Test    | 22          | 2022-05-01 19:07:16.407 |
| 3       | Marked A+ | 50        | 2022-05-01 19:06:16.407 | 3         | Biology Test | 32          | 2022-05-01 19:02:16.407 |
| 4       | Marked A+ | 50        | 2022-05-01 19:06:16.407 | 4         | Math Test    | 22          | 2022-05-01 19:06:20.407 |
```

```
SELECT t1.student, t1.Test, t1.TestOrder, t1.Datetime
, t2.student_, t2.Test_, t2.TestOrder_, t2.Datetime_
FROM tab1 t1
left join tab1 t2 
    ON t2.Test in ('Math Test', 'Biology Test')          
    AND t2.student = t1.student
    AND DATEADD(HOUR, -3, t1.DateTime) <= t2.DateTime and t2.DateTime < DATEADD(HOUR, 3, t1.DateTime) /* Take from the nearest 'Marked A+' (+/-3 hours) */
WHERE t1.Test = 'Marked A+'
```

But I have no I idea how to take the  nearest 'Math Test', 'Biology Test' according to TestOrder column

PS: I am using MSSQL

On the screenshot I highlighted must be taken rows [image]

Comment: Can you explain what "nearest" means with respect to `TestOrder` column- for Student 1 two rows have the same value 32 and all students have the same TestOrder, how is Student2 different from Student1?

Comment: It looks like the desired results are nothing to do with the `TestOrder` column, but the closest depending om `[DateTime]`

Comment: @Stu "nearest" with respect to TestOrder means that if the events with the same datetime were before we take event with highest Test Order

Comment: if the events with the same datetime were after we take event with  lowest Test Order (example student 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses `apply` to match the closest row by `[Datetime]` to the source row. It doesn't deal with duplicates however, for which you haven't clarified any requirements, but see if this works for you?

```
select *
from t
cross apply (
    select top(1) *
    from t t2
    where t.student = t2.student and t2.Test in ('Math Test', 'Biology Test') 
      and Abs(DateDiff(minute,t2.[datetime],t.[datetime]))<= 180
    order by Abs(DateDiff(minute,t2.[datetime],t.[datetime])),
     case when t2.[datetime] > t.[datetime] then TestOrder end ,
     case when t2.[datetime] < t.[datetime] then TestOrder end desc
)m
where t.test='Marked A+';
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ccbfa633feac65b55e216bbe94a0af6)

Comment: I added a comment on your questions

Comment: @Aleksandra I've added to the ordering criteria based on your comments, does this fulfil your requirements? The following [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ccbfa633feac65b55e216bbe94a0af6) provides expected results

Comment: how to realize explicit join for  'Marked A+' on 'Math Test', 'Biology Test'? where t.student = t2.student and t2.[datetime] <> t.[datetime] and t.Test = 'Marked A+' and t2.Test in ('Math Test', 'Biology Test') ? Am I right?

Comment: The `and t2.[datetime] <> t.[datetime]` takes care of that since those `test` values are different to the date of 'Marked A+' - however if that doesn't work for your real data you could replace it with that `in` criteria.

Comment: I asked it, because there might be other different  test  except 'Math Test', 'Biology Test' and I need to join only  'Marked A+' on 'Math Test', 'Biology Test' . I would like to use explicit join there

Comment: where do we have condition in (+/- 3 hours) for  'Math Test', 'Biology Test' ?

Comment: @Aleksandra I've added that criteria in to the answer. I missed the 3-hours criteria but have added something that should work for that also.